# MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException in codeigniter 3.x

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter-3

After migrating a project in CI 2.x to 3.x the following error is shown where i used mongo db, this works fine in codeigniter version 2,

> Message: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://'. Invalid host
>   string in URI.

Db Configuration

```
// Generally will be localhost if you're querying from the machine that Mongo is installed on
$config['mongo_host'] = "localhost";
//$config['mongo_host'] = "xxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com";

// Generally will be 27017 unless you've configured Mongo otherwise
$config['mongo_port'] = 27017;

// The database you want to work from (required)
$config['mongo_db'] = "test_p1";

// Leave blank if Mongo is not running in auth mode
$config['mongo_user'] = "";
$config['mongo_pass'] = "";

// Persistant connections
$config['mongo_persist'] = TRUE;
$config['mongo_persist_key'] = 'ci_mongo_persist';

// Get results as an object instead of an array
$config['mongo_return'] = 'array'; // Set to object

// When you run an insert/update/delete how sure do you want to be that the database has received the query?
// safe = the database has receieved and executed the query
// fysnc = as above + the change has been committed to harddisk <- NOTE: will introduce a performance penalty
$config['mongo_query_safety'] = 'safe';

// Supress connection error password display
$config['mongo_supress_connect_error'] = TRUE;

// If you are having problems connecting try changing this to TRUE
$config['host_db_flag'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: i'hv updated db config.. @pradeep

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383089/how-to-integrate-mongodb-library-in-codeigniter-for-database-connection-with-mon

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter

Comment: ok let me try ,. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may forget to set up db in your local machine.